# spark read csv by default trying to read from Hdfs. How to read local csv files then? Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

initially I was reading a csv file(local) placed in all of the Nodes in my standalone cluster.

```
df = spark.read.csv('/data/TRX_FILE/1000_trx.csv',header=True)
#Everything was fine then
```

Now I installed HDFS and set the conf path in spark-env.sh of all the nodes

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf  ###to read/avoid core_site.xml  error
```

And tried to read same csv, which I intend to do some analysis and then will write to Hdfs path.  But till now my csv is in LOCAL PATH.

```
#when tried 
df = spark.read.csv('/data/TRX_FILE/1000_trx.csv',header=True)
#Error:
 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
  pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://Myspark:9000/data/TRX_FILE/1000_trx.csv;'
```

My question is : why even it trying to read from a HDFS???. I have not even mention a HDFS path also.... whera as my intention or requirement is to read that csv from local...I am merely confused about the problem and solution.
Is there anything I am doing wrong here???plz correct me also.

Kindly help me experts.. Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Use `file:///data/...` if you don't want to read from HDFS

Comment: @cricket_007- It worked, Thanks... And can u plz post that in answer so that i will accept that as answer.